# Not transferring value from PHP to echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

More of a php problem than anything else.

I have a really weird problem. I'm doing a _POST request from PHP which is working for my query, but when I try to include that same number into a echo, it's not working. What's going on?

I'm doing the following:

```
     $pageNumber = $_POST['pageNumber'];
     $startIndex = $pageNumber*10;
     $sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit $startIndex, 10";
     // this works    

     $string = "";   
     $fetcheddata = $mysqlConnection->query($sqlQuery); 
     if($fetcheddata!=null && $fetcheddata->num_rows>0){
             while ($row = $fetcheddata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                     $string.="<p>".$row['id'].",".$row['first_name'].",".$row['last_name']."    </p>";                          

             }               
     }     
     // this also works when I load with different data and 
     // I know this because the data from the database is of
     // the right index which means $pageNumber IS INFACT incrementing

     echo "<div class='newData'>INFO: ".$string. "</div><div id = 'dom-target' style='display    : none'>".$pageNumber."TESTING META DATA</div>";
     // but for some reason this doesn't give me the correct
     // $pageNumber, it always gives me zero.
```

when I try to echo out the $pageNumber into html, I'm always getting 0 on the request, even though the number is obviously incrementing since the entire query works, or else it wouldn't be pulling from the database correctly. But it is working! So why won't it print out correctly? Am I going crazy?

EDIT: just to clarify, the query IS WORKING, the last line of code does not print out the correct $pageNumber, even though that number exsists and I know that *because* the query worked.

This is the php error log:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Users-Computer.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 25 12:58:16.260705 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 51] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 25 12:58:16.260985 2015] [core:notice] [pid 51] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

**SOLUTION:**

I found a solution to this problem by just using a different $_POST('newVariable'). For some reason, when I used the $sql query for anything before the query, the php variable lost it's value. I don't know why it did that but the solution was just to use each variable once. I've seen this question posted a few other places as well.

Specifically, I added `echo "<div class = 'metadata'>".$sqlQuery."</div>";` right after `$sqlQuery` was defined. Before this, the query worked, after this, the query didn't work. I still don't know why.

Comment: You wrote *it's now working* - Did you mean to say: It's NOT working? I don't get it.

Comment: I meant to say NOT working. That was my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The reason why it's not showing the page number is because of `style='display : none'`

- Either remove it, or do `style='display : block'`

or `inline` or other CSS method you wish to use.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display

Another thing, I notice is the word "ajax" in your error logs.

You'll need to show that, the issue could be in there also.

---

Original answer from the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28731364/1):

You're missing both a `$` and semi-colon in

```
_POST['pageNumber']
```

change that to

```
$_POST['pageNumber'];
```

It's a superglobal

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Then this line

```
$sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit $startIndex, 10";
                                    ^^ ^^^
```

You're probably trying to do an `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` with `asc`

So, it's hard to say which column you want to sort or group.

Either try:

```
select * from my_table group by id asc
```

or

```
select * from my_table order by id asc
```

I.e.

```
ORDER | GROUP BY column ASC
```

If you're not ordering or grouping by, then remove the `asc` from your query.

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

as per

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

---

Also, check for errors in your query using:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I pasted in the post wrong and fixed it now, but let me clarify my problem. The query to get data from the database is WORKING CORRECTLY, but when I echo out the $pageNumber, it's not echoing out on the last line of code. Everything else works fine.

Comment: @user3049865 You're welcome. Can you tell me what value is being passed for POST? Do `var_dump($pageNumber);` or `var_dump($_POST['pageNumber']);` to make sure a value is being passed. Also Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @user3049865 Your code shows `_POST['pageNumber']` but are you in fact using `$_POST['pageNumber'];`?

Comment: @user3049865 This `$sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit $startIndex, 10";` that isn't right. The "id" and "asc", is missing something here. I made an edit also. Reload the answer.

Comment: I've added <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); and I'm checking the error log but I've never done this before so it might take me a minute. I did fix the syntax to $_POST['pageNumber'];

Comment: @user3049865 Reload the answer and go through it all again. I've made a few edits. Plus, what are the column types?

Comment: @user3049865 Reload my answer, at the top; that's why.

Comment: Thanks again. I should have clerified that I'm pulling the data from javascript with `getElementById('dom-target')` and putting in somewhere else that doesn't have `display: none`. I know it won't display here. I also tried what someone else suggested and still got back `0 OR 0 OR 0 TESTING META DATA` for the response, even through the query worked. This was after I tried changing the last line to `echo "<div class='newData'>INFO: ".$string. "</div><div id = 'dom-target' style='display    : none'>".$pageNumber." OR ". $_POST['pageNumber'] ." OR ". $startIndex/10 . " TESTING META DATA</div>";`

Comment: You're welcome. You'll need to post your form in relation to `$_POST['pageNumber']`. Remember, in PHP that variables are case-sensitive. So if your form's element is named "pagenumber" with a lowercase "n", then that could be it also. @user3049865 I need to see more code and the one for that related POST.

Comment: @user3049865 Are you sure your form's set to a POST method and not a GET method? If the method is not included in `<form>`, it defaults to GET. Again, I need to see the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

This line also looks incorrect:

```
$sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit $startIndex, 10";
```

Should be:

```
$sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit " . $startIndex . ", 10";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like that works too, but the query for me wasn't the problem, both lines do work. Not sure what that means.

Comment: @JasonMurray With double quotes you can use variables inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this one, and see which values I'd get from it.

```
$pageNumber = $_POST['pageNumber'];
$startIndex = $pageNumber*10;
$sqlQuery = "select * from my_table id asc limit $startIndex, 10";

$string = "";   
$fetcheddata = $mysqlConnection->query($sqlQuery); 
if($fetcheddata!=null && $fetcheddata->num_rows>0){
        while ($row = $fetcheddata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $string.="<p>".$row['id'].",".$row['first_name'].",".$row['last_name']."    </p>";                          
         }               
}

echo "<div class='newData'>INFO: ".$string. "</div><div id = 'dom-target' style='display    : none'>".$pageNumber." OR ". $_POST['pageNumber'] ." OR ". $startIndex/10 . " TESTING META DATA</div>";
```

Comment: I'm still getting zeros for everything. "0 OR 0 OR 0 TESTING META DATA". Thanks though.